# Hero Images fail to load using Contentful and gatsby-starter-blog with AWS Amplify

Tags: gatsby, aws-amplify, contentful

I am using https://github.com/contentful/starter-gatsby-blog to try and whip up a personal blog whilst at the same time learning Contentful and AWS Amplify deploys.  I have managed to build and deploy using AWS Amplify at stevegibbard.co.uk and I can add a page and see that reflected in my deploy.  The issue I have is that the Hero images across the site are failing to dynamically load from Contentful, instead only the placeholder loads.

When I run the code locally using npm run dev I see the images load correctly, first placeholders are shown and then the full images are revealed when the page loads.

Note: this is just the canned implementation of HeroImage/BlogPost code from git and I am using sample images that were provided by the example.

If I look at DevTools for the images when loading the stevegibbard.co.uk site I do not see any errors, but I do see that images appear to be coming back with a text/html type ?

[DevTools output for AWS deployed site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62aog.png)

If I load the page locally I see image type octet-stream, I also then see lazy-hydrate initiating the load of the images.

[DevTools output for locally deployed site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FBFd.png)

A sample of a HeroImage usage:

```
`   const posts = get(this, 'props.data.allContentfulBlogPost.nodes')
    const [author] = get(this, 'props.data.allContentfulPerson.nodes')
...
        <Hero
          image={author.heroImage.gatsbyImage}
          title={author.name}
          content={author.shortBio}
        />
...

query HomeQuery {
    allContentfulBlogPost(sort: { fields: [publishDate], order: DESC }) {
      nodes {
        title
        slug
        publishDate(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
        tags
        heroImage {
          gatsbyImage(
            layout: FULL_WIDTH
            placeholder: BLURRED
            width: 424
            height: 212
          )
        }
        description {
          raw
        }
      }
    }`
```

Could anyone recommend how I would go about debugging this further please?

I have tried removing the BLURRED placeholder and I see that the images still stick at the placeholder state, except in this case they use DOMINANT_COLOR for the placeholder

Comment: I presume you are calling `getImage()` inside Hero?

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by adding the avif file format as an exception to the 200 rewrite in the canned aws amplify redirects (see below).

[Amplify redirect config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofzHy.png)